# How do I run code coverage analysis for my tests automatically after building my solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

How can I execute **Code Coverage Analysis** on my **unit tests** automatically each time I execute a build process from my development machine?

I have searched the internet but I have not found any related questions or posts.

Comment: Will that run code analysis too? I thought that was just executing tests alone.

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. "Run tests after build" is available in Ultimate, but it never executes "Run CodeAnalysis after build". I suspect because it's a much slower operation. If you need this, you'll have to get something like NCrunch http://www.ncrunch.net/. And you'll want to submit a suggestion on the https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: You better install a CI server (Like Jenkins) and call that via Visual studio post build command.

Answer (score 1):

According to info from MSDN:

1. In Team Explorer, open **Builds**, and then add or edit a build definition.
2. On the **Process** page, expand **Automated Tests**, **Test Source**, **Run Settings**. Set **Type of Run Settings File** to **Code Coverage Enabled**.

   If you have more than one Test Source definition, repeat this step for each one.

   - But there is no field named **Type of Run Settings File**.

     Under **Automated Tests**, select **Test Assembly** and choose the ellipsis button **[...]** at the end of the line. In the **Add/Edit Test Run** dialog box, under **Test Runner**, choose **Visual Studio Test Runner**.

[image]

After the build runs, the code coverage results are attached to the test run and appear in the build summary.

Source:

1. [Using Code Coverage to Determine How Much Code is being Tested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx) (look for **Analyzing code coverage in the build service**)
2. [Run tests in your build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using **Code Coverage** for testing, you will determine how much of the project's code is actually being tested by coded tests, in this case **unit testing**.  Code Coverage is a feature that Visual Studio uses to guard against **bugs** etc.

**Requirements are to have Visual Studio Premium**

To use analyze Code Coverage in Visual Studio on unit tests in the Test Explorer in Visual Studio, follow the steps bellow:

1. On the Test menu in Visual Studio select the option **Analyze Code Coverage**
2. Then if you want to see which lines have been run, chosse the option **Show Code Coverage Coloring**

The Code Coverage Results will usually show the results of the most recent run that you have done.

The code coverage can also be used to view previous results.

The coverage coloring might be incorrect if the source code has changed since the .coverage file was generated.

For automated Code coverage do the following steps:

1. Select Test Assembly and choose the ellipsis button.
2. In the Add/Edit Test Run dialog box, choose Visual Studio Test Runner.

You can also **Merge** results from different Code Coverage Runs.

Here is a link if you want to Customize Code Coverage Analysis:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

Here is a link for Analyzing Code COverage in Build Verification Test:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159524.aspx

Here is a link for Troubleshooting Code Coverage:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159523.aspx

Sources can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx